# How do I yank, delete, and paste a group of lines without moving the cursor?

Tags: vim

Let's say I'm on line 25, and I want to grab lines 15-17, delete them, and paste them on my current line.

Can I do that in a single command?

I'm aware of things like this (and other similar combos):

```
:-10,-7t.
:15,17d
```

p.s. If there is already a q/a for this I apologize, I just failed to find it.

Comment: For awareness, there's also a [Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com) Exchange.

Comment: Oh thank you! I wasn't aware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you're looking for is *move*.

If you want to move the lines after the current line then

```
:15,17m.
```

This will result in something like

```
original line 24
original line 25
original line 15
original line 16
original line 17
original line 26
```

If you want it *before* the current line then

```
:15,17m-1
```

Which will result in something like

```
original line 24
original line 15
original line 16
original line 17
original line 25
original line 26
```